# Periodically delete .torrent files from a specified directory?

Tags: windows-7, script

How do I make this happen? A scheduled batch file seems like it might work but I have no idea how. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this:

> The Task Scheduler can be used to execute tasks such as starting an
>   application, sending an e-mail, or showing a message box. Tasks can be
>   scheduled to execute:
>
> ```
> When a specific system event occurs.
> At a specific time.
> At a specific time on a daily schedule.
> At a specific time on a weekly schedule.
> At a specific time on a monthly schedule.
> At a specific time on a monthly day-of-week schedule.
> When the computer enters an idle state.
> When the task is registered.
> When the system is booted.
> When a user logs on.
> When a Terminal Server session changes state.
> ```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can see an example to get start to develop your own "clearing torrent files" task.